# How to read files and then assign each file integer to an array list?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, file-io, nullpointerexception

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NotWorking {   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // The files that I need to open
        // They contain integers (points on a graph)
        // Ex: 74 0 80 100 150 60 150
        String[] names = {"Test.txt", "Test2.in", "test3.in", "Test4.in", "Test5.in"};
        // Create 5 list
        ArrayList<Integer>[] textFiles = new ArrayList[5];

        // for loop through each file
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            Scanner scanner;
            // open file
            scanner = new Scanner(new File(names[i]));
            // @fileNumber is one of 5 list
            int fileNumber = 0;
            // add each integer to the correct list
            while (scanner.hasNextInt()){
            // line below this is where it says NullPointer Exception
            textFiles[fileNumber].add(scanner.nextInt());       
            }enter code here
            // Trying to see if lists are made correctly and also increasing fileNumber after
            // each file is processed
            System.out.println(textFiles[fileNumber]);
            fileNumber ++;      
        }   
    }
    }
```

I need to open files (.txt and .in) that are given as an array. I use a for loop to loop through them and then open them, but as I read through them I want to use the data from them. So my idea was to create 5 array list and put the data in those. But I can't seem to figure it out. It keeps giving me NullPointer Exception. Also, I need to be able to put the data into another method. An example would be "Quad(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, dx, dy)" and each file has the coordinates I need. Is the array list the best way to accomplish it?

Comment: you only created an array for containing arraylists. You haven't actually *created any arraylists* yet.

Comment: But you haven't created 5 array lists.  You haven't created any array lists. What you've created is an empty array of length 5 of type array list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate memory to arraylists before using them.

This is the reason why it threw NullPointerException as textFiles[0],... are null, and you're trying to perform operation on a null!

```
textFiles[fileNumber] = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
// call constructor as above to allocate memory to each individual arraylists.
while (scanner.hasNextInt()){   
        textFiles[fileNumber].add(scanner.nextInt());       
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is awfully low level - going to give you some "starting points" to work with more helpful abstractions:

It might be much easier to read **all lines** from **all files** into a single `List<String>` though (assuming that all files have the same format).

And that can easily be achieved with [Files.readAllLines()](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.nio.file/Files/Java_Files_readAllLines_Path_path_Charset_cs_.htm)

Unless this is homework and you are asked to all that "manually"; you really should rely on such high level abstractions. There is not much sense in implementing something that already exists. The other reason to not do it this way would be if you are talking about **huge** files; so that you simply want all those lines in memory at the same point in time.

And even when you don't use readAllLines to read all files in one shot; you can still use the method to read one file after the other in **one shot**.

No matter how you collect your information; you then have a `List<String>` containing your raw data; now could be using [regular expressions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm) to easily match the numbers in those strings; to then use Integer.parseInt() to convert them to int. Simple example:

```
String numbersAsString = "1 2 3 4";
String[] separatedNumbers = numbersAsString.split(" ");
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
for (String oneNumber : separatedNumbers) {
  numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(oneNumber));
}
```

And finally, "converting" 4 ints or Integers into some other string representation is really easy; like:

```
String toQuad(int a, int b, ....... ) {
  return "Quad(" + a +"," + b ...
```

Comment: They are all the same format, but they contain integers. I'm new to Java so this may be a dumb question, but all the files contain points on a graph. So they need to be integers. Would I just do List<Integer> instead of List<String>? Also, how would I extract the data from the list so I can use it in a method?

Comment: That is already in my updated answer. No, changing the list type doesn't magically convert Strings to numbers. You have to write code for that.